# Satisfies CR-equations, but is not complex differentiable in 0

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ given by:
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/z^4} &\text{if } z \neq 0 \\
0  &\text{if } z = 0.
\end{cases}$$

Show that it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations everywhere, but that it is not complex-differentiable in 0.

I have shown that $\frac{df}{d\overline{z}} = 0$ for all $z$, so that it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. But i have no idea how to show that it is not complex differentiable in $0$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(r e^{i \pi/4})$ for $r \to 0$ and conclude that $f$ is
not even continuous at $z=0$.