# NOT Differentiable in $z \Rightarrow$ NOT Holomorphic in $z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, definition

I was studying complex analysis and suddently I got some kind of stupid question in my head, which is the following:

If I want to prove that a complex function isn't holomorphic at the origin (only an example), is it enough to prove that it's not differentiable there? i.e., is it enough to prove that
\begin{equation*}
f'(z) = \lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0} \hspace{.2cm} \text{does not exist}?
\end{equation*}

Or do I have to check if the CR-Equations aren't verified in any neighbourhood of the origin? (If they aren't verified, then the function isn't holomorphic).

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Complex differentiability $\iff$ holomorphicity $\iff$ analyticity $\iff$ Cauchy-Riemann equations hold (and several more iffs). Holomorphicity is a really strong condition.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @davidlowryduda Complex differentiability is a point-by-point condition. It is not equivalent to the following two. Complex differentiability in a neighborhood is what is equivalent to the rest.. Likewise, Cauchy-Riemann equations alone is also not equivalent. [Example for Cauchy-Riemann](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1802036/917479). Example for differentiability $z\mapsto z|z|$ at $z=0$.

Comment: @plop You make an excellent point. Yes, it is necessary to be differentiable in a neighborhood.

Comment: The implication in the title is the opposite of the one you're actually asking about.

Comment: Hello @HansLundmark . Actually, what I am asking for is: NOT Differentiable in $z \Rightarrow$ NOT holormophic in $z$. And, from José Carlos Santos answer I believe that this is true. I will update the title anyway, thanks for noticing!

Comment: Since “not Q implies not P” is equivalent to “P implies Q”, the old title was really the opposite. But anyway, now it looks OK!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under *any* definition of holomorphic function that I am aware of, all you have to check is that that limit doesn't exist. Note that it is perfectly possible that $(0,0)$ is a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations and, even so, $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ (take, say $f(z)=\sqrt{|\operatorname{Re}(z)\operatorname{Im}(z)|}$).

Comment: Thanks! Really helpfull :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this suffices. Being holomorphic in a point means to be complex differentiable in that point (and, moreover, any point of a neighborhood). So being differentiable in one point is necessary for being holomorphic in that point.

Comment: Thanks! Clarified my doubt!